# How do I find the historical arrival procedure GOLDN6 for SJC that is no longer valid?

Tags: faa, instrument-procedures

I don’t know exactly when this procedure disappeared.  It was used in 2013, but not sure how much longer.  It was used primarily by SEA to SJC flights.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE.

Comment: And, to pre-empt objections about "resource location is off-topic," the real question here is about a method: how to go about researching retired procedures. And that's a perfectly valid question - because the answer **isn't** to go buy them from Amazon or from Sporty's or from Wal Mart or etc.

Comment: No idea how well it'd actually work, but I wonder if an old flight simulator with an "out-dated" database might have some useful info. It wouldn't be the whole plate, but you may be able to get fixes/coordinates out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that the numeric part of the arrival (6 in GOLDN6, for example) changes over time. Maybe the FAA adds, or removes, or changes a speed restriction at a given waypoint on the arrival. The number will go up, and the new version will be effective on a given date. Then in some number of months, something else changes, and the number increments again. When it gets to 9, the next revision goes back to 1.  (Which is okay, since the last GOLDN1 was now years in the past, and what's important is differentiating the current procedure from one that was recently superseded.)

***Typically***, these revisions are pretty minor, and when airspace gets revised on a large scale, the old procedure names are all retired, and all new procedures are published with all new names.

All of that to say, if you search for "GOLDN arrival SJC" (and don't let the search engine *helpfully* substitute 'golden' in the query), you may find a chart of the GOLDN4 or GOLDN5, which would most likely be quite similar to the one you're interested in.

I imagine that the FAA TERPS office keeps archival copies of everything that they've ever published, as (probably) would OAK Center and the NORCAL TRACON, and (almost certainly) Jeppesen, but those avenues start becoming a lengthy research project, trying to get in touch with the right person in the right office.

Hopefully this helps with the search.

Comment: Turns out that "GOLDN arrival SJC" is less useful than "Golden Gate arrival SJC" -  the first result for the latter is: https://www.fly.faa.gov/Information/west/zoa/sfo/atcCharts/SFO_STAR_00375GOLDENGATE.pdf

Comment: I am interested in revisions of GOLDN.  GOLDN6 was the last version.  I did google it and found only one link on flightaware.com to a flight about 8 years ago.  Unfortunately, corresponding  decode page was unable to display the waypoints and lat, long.  So if anyone has ideas on how to find this history it would be appreciated.  Is there a way to search archived NOTAMs?  I would appreciate very specific instructions.  Here is the one flight I found https://flightaware.com/live/flight/ASA324/history/20130718/1925ZZ/KSEA/KSJC.

Comment: If this is for research of some kind, Oakland ARTCC (located in Fremont) would probably have the answer in their Airspace and Procedures office. The A&S office keeps current procedures, but should also have access to archive data. Their main switchboard is at 510-745-3000.

Comment: The GOLDN standard terminal arrival route (STAR) was decommissioned about a year ago (I write ATC simulations for Denver ARTCC, and have to be current on stuff like this). It had transitions from the east over OAL VOR (in addition to transitions from SEA and others), and we saw it a lot here in Denver. VOR-based STARs are going the way of the dodo, however. RNAV STARs are the future.

Comment: Googling does little good if the sought after document is deleted from databases, as in the case of approach plates, and procedure documents like SIDs & STARs is done, for obvious reasons. And anyway, I'd strongly advice against "google it" -answers, as they simply are not usefull at all.

Comment: @Jpe61  There is more in the answer than simply "google it," but if that being included is worth the dv, be my guest. See also first comment, above.

Comment: Fair enough, I edited the answer to bring the usefull part to the front. Took the liberty to completely remove the obvious.